# Error after trying to delete contents of field in table MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database with a table in it that contains member profile information. I want to restore their avatars the default which will involve me deleting the entries already made. The table name is core_members and the field is called pp_main_photo.

I have used this:

```
UPDATE core_members SET pp_main_photo = NULL;
```

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Not the cause of the problem but you don't have a `WHERE` clause in your update which means it will update the whole table, which is probably not what you want (or is it?). Also, are you really using the query you mentioned above?

Comment: I found that query in my searches, no one mentioned the WHERE component. I will try it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE core_members
SET pp_main_photo = NULL
WHERE pp_main_photo is not null;

Answer (score 0):

```
update core_members set pp_main_photo = null
```

or if your `pp_main_photo` column does not allow `null`:

```
update core_members set pp_main_photo = ''
```

Some SQL tools that are used for executing DB queries prevent updates on ALL records (queries without a `where` clause) by default. You can configure that and remove that savety setting or you can add a `where` clause that is `true` for all records and update all anyway like this:

```
update core_members 
set pp_main_photo = null
where 1 = 1
```

Comment: This returns an error of #1054 - Unknown column 'core_members.ID_MEMBER' in 'where clause'

I don't need to specify the member ID all members will experience this change to the avatar.